# iOS N How to get all the User-Agent String

Tags: ios, user-agent

**Hello, there has been a problem bothering me, trouble respect your answer**

**To obtain a single UserAgent String is simple**
:`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148`
...

**Want to get all iOS versions of all the UserAgent String**
whatismybrowser.com download error

> The iOS Or Safari Or AppleWebKit , if there is a more complete record
>   is available for download

Stackoverflow was used for the first time, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I run the website you're talking about: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com

We block crawlers from the listing, which is why you're probably getting the download error. We constantly get slammed by bots that don't "play nice" - sending thousands of requests per minute, crawling the site excessively; some bots are broken too - requesting the same page over and over and over again. We block any activity like this because it overloads the servers and makes the site non-responsive for legitimate users.

If you want a database dump of over 3 million user agent records (and growing!), containing all the detailed parse information that our user agent parser provides, as well as interesting meta data (first seen, last seen, times seen etc), then we are happy to offer it for a small fee:

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/api/features/download-useragent-database